# Insertion syntax for interval data type in postgres

Tags: database, postgresql

I created a `table` with following the `fields` and I have used a interval field to store duration of the courses. I want to insert interval time in `DD:HH` and couldn't find the syntax for it.

Anybody can help me with this insertion syntax with above format `DD:HH` . Thanks in advance.

```
CREATE TABLE practical.course
(
  course_id character(3) primary key,
  course_name character varying(30),
  duration interval,
  dept_id integer references practical.department(dept_id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE practical.course
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-INTERVAL-INPUT-EXAMPLES

Comment: Additionally consider the [make_interval](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-datetime.html) function (introduced in the 9.4 version)

Answer (score 3):

You can insert as follows..

```
insert into practical.course(course_id,course_name, duration, dept_id)
values('104','Mathematical Engineering','40:00:00',1);
```

If you want to add days you can add `'no_of_days 40:00:00'` instead `'40:00:00'`. You can insert in different formats and they are available in above link on the comment.